# How to export an FBX file with textures?

Tags: export, .fbx

Hi I am currently exporting FBX animated files from Blender 2.8, with textures mapped onto the model. I need to be able to zip everything so that the file can be imported into Adobe Aero but a problem occurs where only the colour texture is applied, no roughness or normals are there. My question is am I missing something at the Blender stage? I use Principled BSDF to assign the textures but maybe that isn't correct in this instance?
Any help would be great.

Comment: Can you share your node setup for us to have a look?

Answer (score 1):

FBX does support embedded textures, and has done for a long time.
http://download.autodesk.com/us/fbx/20112/FBX_SDK_HELP/index.html?url=WS1a9193826455f5ff7b1de9f8127315f1b54-5a50.htm,topicNumber=d0e1054

For some reason, blender does not support this (I'm sure it used to).

Answer (score 0):

The FBX format can't do that, you will need to export your textures manually then plug them when importing your model.
If you want to export your model with the textures assigned to the Principled BSDF then import them automatically use the .glb (lighter, recommended) or .glTF file format.

Comment: As far as I'm aware FBX can embed texture though with *Path Mode* set to *Copy* and *Embed Textures* enabled.